# Change html that contain a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have an html with a jquery UI dialog.
I then change the div containing the dialog.
But the content of the dialog does not change.
I want to be able to change the dialog and its containing div together.
If i change only the dialog div it works as expected but that is not what i need.

Example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/JpLzh/13/

The text inside the dialog should change from 'original' to 'new' but it does not.
The text outside the dialog does change from 'main' to 'altered main'.

What am i doing wrong, and how can i overcome this problem ?

**EDIT**
I need the dialog to work even before the change take place. the change can happen long time after the html is created.

the html

```
<div id="main">
main
<br>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="dialog">
    original
</div>
</div>
<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            draggable:true,
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>
```

the onload javascript

```
$('#main').html('<div id="main">altered main<br><button id="opener">Open Dialog</button><div id="dialog">new</div></div>');
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            draggable:true,
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JpLzh/9/ Check is this what u want ?

Comment: nope, it need to have the original value until i change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
Looks like i cant change the dialog with its containing div because it is already a dialog by the  .dialog() method and when i change the containing html it does not affect the already created dialog.

the solution i found was to destroy the old dialog using the .destroy() method and then create a new one from the new altered html.

my solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/JpLzh/12/

```
<div id="main">
main
<br>
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
<button id="changer">Change div</button>
<div id="dialog">
    original
</div>
</div>
<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            draggable:true,
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
</script>


function change_div()
{
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
$('#main').html('<div id="main">altered main<br><button id="opener">Open Dialog</button><div    id="dialog">new</div></div>');

$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            draggable:true,
});

$( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
}


$( "#changer" ).click(function() {
  change_div();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're creating 2 dialogs. To change the content of the dialog, all you need to do is change the dialog div:

```
    <div id="main">
        main
        <br>
        <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
            <button id="changer">change Dialog</button>
        <div id="dialog">
            original
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 200,
                    width: 200,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable:false,
                    draggable:true,
    });

        $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
          $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        });


        $( "#changer" ).click(function() {
          $( "#dialog" ).html("new");
        });
</script>
```

Comment: i know i can change the dialog div, but i want to change it with the div that contain it.

Comment: Kyle's solution shows the correct principle. If you change the containing div, it will change the dialog contents, no matter where or when you change it. See http://jsfiddle.net/6Ypck/5/ So instead of `.dialog()` use `.html()` (or `.text()` or whatever that changes the div).

Comment: like i said, i want to change the entire div that contain the dialog and not just the dialog.in your example you use .html() on the dialog selector while i want to use it on the containing div selector.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a dialog from element `#dialog`, the element is moved out of its original parent (`#main`). If you change the parent's content while the dialog is being displayed, you're not changing the dialog (which is a good thing, otherwise the dialog would be removed).

What you need to do is to change the dialog contents separately:

```
$( '#main' ).html( 'The new content except #dialog' );
$( '#dialog' ).html( 'New dialog contents' );
```

(By the way, you shouldn't do this: `$( '#main' ).html( '<div id="main">...' )` You're changing the *inner* HTML contents, so you shouldn't repeat the container. Otherwise the result is `<div id="main"><div id="main">...`)

Comment: this sound right, i found a way though, by using destroy and creating the dialog again.and you are also right about changing the inner html, i did not notice.

Answer (score 0):

You're duplicating your script code, but the code running is the one on the HTML part (between  tags) and it is missing the line #1 from the javascript part.

You should put your Javascript part inside this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //JS Code here...
});
```

and delete the  part inside your HTML.

Check: http://jsfiddle.net/fabio_silva/6Ypck/

Comment: What do you mean? The dialog works before the change. You make the change in this line:

$('#main').html('<div id="main">altered main<br><button id="opener">Open Dialog</button><div id="dialog">new</div></div>');

Try to delete that and you have your div with the original content. What does it have to do with?

Comment: i have the dialog but after a few minutes i want to change it and its containing div.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code it will work it.....

```
$('#main').html('<div id="main">altered main<br><button id="opener" onclick="OpenDialog();">Open Dialog</button><div id="dialog">new</div></div>');
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            draggable:true,
});

function OpenDialog() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
}
```

after processing it will generate this html code

```
<div id="main">
main
<br>
<button id="opener" onclick="OpenDialog()">Open Dialog</button>
<div id="dialog">
    original
</div>
</div>
<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 800,
            modal: true,
            resizable:false,
            draggable:true,
});

function OpenDialog() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
}
</script>
```